# curl error, on array apikey

Tags: php, api, curl

I have this, array of api keys.

```
<?php
/*Variables - Start*/

$apiKey = array (
'phweb' => 'm776703283-58528ee50653b191361a97c8',
'phemail' => 'm776701721-d532d1d2d020749423d80200',
);


$url = array (
'phweb' => "http://api.uptimerobot.com/getMonitors?apiKey=" . $apiKey['phweb'] . "&logs=1" . "&customUptimeRatio=1-7-30" . "&format=xml",
'phemail' => "http://api.uptimerobot.com/getMonitors?apiKey=" . $apiKey['phemail'] . "&logs=1" . "&customUptimeRatio=1-7-30" . "&format=xml",
);

/*Variables - End*/
?>
```

and I have this when working with curl

```
<?php
/*Check Curl if Installed - Start*/
function is_curl_installed() {
if  (in_array  ('curl', get_loaded_extensions())) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}
/*Check Curl if Installed - End*/
/*Curl Request - Start*/
function curl_seasson($url) {
$c = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$responseXML = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);

return $responseXML;
}
/*Curl Request - End*/
?>
```

and I got this error (refer to the image above)

[image]

Actually, I'm trying to submit 2 api request (curl) as you can see in my apikey array, is that possible? what seems the problem? any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you!

Comment: The errors are pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the `$url` variable to `curl_init` in it's raw form. `curl_init` takes a string for the URL, and you're passing an array. This should get you started:

```
foreach ($url as $apiUrl)
{
    $apiResponse = curl_seasson($apiUrl);
    var_dump($apiResponse);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. yeah foreach is what im thinking recently but I just dont know how to do it. anyway, my concept was loop through an array of apikeys, send api request by each apikey and loop each result and put each responds that was thrown by the api, any ideas or clue how to achieve that? sorry for the noob2x question. im new with the curl.